# Retrieve all hashes in a page for URL use

Tags: html, url, hyperlink

I am trying to copy a link from this site (stack overflow), but I like the link to include a hash so when someone clicks on the link they go directly to the answer I would like them to see. How can I find the hashes in a page?

Example:

```
http://www.blahblah.com/index.php#label
```

How can I know there is a `#label`, and how to find it?

Comment: Manually or with some language? You can see source code and check all `<a href = "#whatever">` (anchor tags) you find. Ctrl+F and writting `href = "#` or `href="#` will help a lot. That's just 1 of all possible solutions if you don't make the question more specific (;

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia Manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the hash is simply the ID attribute of any element in the page.

You can see them in the source or the DOM inspector.

Comment: Can you make a link to a part of the page even if there's no anchor pointing at that? So I could point to this answer just doing [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664650#answer-17664698](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664650#answer-17664698)? Edit: yes I could! Great, +1!

Comment: @SLaks
Is your answer for all sites? Or is it only specific to this site?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

`var hash = window.location.hash;`

Answer (score 0):

There might not be a simple answer for your here.  In a pure HTML context (i.e. excluding javascript functionality).  The has would reference an anchor on the page like this:

```
<a name="label"></a>
```

So you could just look for named anchors.

Now, if you are talking about javascript functionality it gets much more complex. Via javascript you can use a hash tag like that and make it do any number of things (like show a hidden element with `id="label"`, download some content asynchronously based on that hash, etc.  So there might not be an easy way to determine allowable values.